# Django Python Error: Reverse for 'user-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, django

I'm building a Django app using a popular tutorial (by @CoreyMSchafer) as a starting point. I'm getting the below error when I load `http://localhost:8000/test/` in my browser.

```
Reverse for 'user-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']
```

When I load `http://localhost:8000` the app works, which is weird because the only difference between that and the `/test` link is that in `http://localhost:8000` I run the `PostListView.as_view()` (as seen in blog/urls.py) and at `/test` I run `GameListView.as_view()`. But the only difference between those views is that I use the Game_c model in `/test` and the Post model at `http://localhost:8000`, but they are very similar models.

**CODE:**
models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime # timezone takes timezone into consideration (even though it doesn't seem to)

# we're inheriting from the models.Model
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100) # character field
    content = models.TextField() # Unrestricted text
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # author is a one-to-many relationship which uses a foreign key
    # the argument to ForeignKey is the related table
    # on_delete tells django to delete all posts by a user when that user is deleted
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Convenience method to print out the title of a Post
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self): # todo: uncomment
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Game_c(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField() # Unrestricted text
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100) # character field
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name # return game name when game.objects.all() is called
```

blog/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from .models import Post #import the Post object ('.' because in same directory)
from .models import Game_c
from django.db import connection

# def home(request):
#     # This is a "Dictionary"
#     context = {
#         'posts': Post.objects.all() # takes actual data from DB
#     }
#     return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5


class GameListView(ListView):
    model = Game_c
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'games'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        # perform raw query to games__c from salesforce
        games = Game_c.objects.raw('''SELECT id as id, name as name, platform__c as platform, createddate as created_date
                                  FROM salesforce.game__c''')
        print('about to print games...')
        for game in games:
            print('Name: ' + game.name + '; Platform: ' + game.platform)
        return games


class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

django_project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), #default "admin" page supplied by Django?
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'
         ),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

blog/base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Game Exchange - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Game Exchange</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Game Exchange</a> <!--blog-home is the name we gave to our url pattern. It gets the absolute path-->
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">About</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">FAQ</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-about' %}">Search Proposed Trades</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">Your Matches</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">Propose New Trade</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
              {% else %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
              <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message }}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Trade Requests</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

blog/home.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Welcome to Game Exchange!</h1>
<br /> <br />
<h4>What is Game Exchange?</h4>
<p>Game exchange automatically sets up a trade for you with nearby gamers who own the game you want, and want the game you own.</p>
<br />
<span>
    <button style="margin-left: 20%; padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px" class="btn btn-outline-info">Sign In</button>
    <button style="margin-left: 20%; padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px" class="btn btn-outline-info">Sign Up</button>
</span>
<br /> <br /> <br />
<h4>Recent Proposed Trades</h4>
    {% for game in games %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
<!--              <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>-->
                <small class="text-muted"><b>Created:</b> {{ game.created_date|date:"M j, Y - gA" }} UTC</small>
<!--                <small class="text-muted"><b>Last Modified:</b> {{ post.last_modified|date:"M j, Y - gA" }} UTC</small>-->
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'blog-home' }">{{ game.name }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content">Platform: {{ game.platform }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}


    {% if is_paginated %}

      {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
      {% endif %}

      {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_obj.number == num %}
          <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
        {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
          <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
      {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**Additional Notes:**
The tutorial I am following is at: https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Django_Blog/13-Deployment-Heroku/django_project

Comment: `post` in `{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}` does not exists, it is `game`, not `post`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you mean the line in blog/home.html? But that line is commented out

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem NOO WAY you figured it out about 30 seconds after posting! Thank you so much!! I guess since it's a "bind" variable or w.e., it doesn't matter that it was commented out. Thanks again!

Comment: no, you used HTML comment, but Django does not care about that when *rendering* the template. It "listens" to `{# ... #}` for comment that it will not render.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As @WillemVanOnsem pointed out, even if a bind variable, such as `{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}` in my case is commented out, it can still cause template render errors. After deleting that line, my problem was fixed